# DataTables - ColReorder plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using the DataTable plugin ColReorder, and it works great! However, according to it's limited documentation (https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) one of the features is the ability to exclude one (or more) columns from being able to be reordered.  I need this functionality because there are certain columns in my dataTables that I do not want the user moving from their position.  I am planning on having a specific class on the table headers that I want to be "static" positioned, and then exclude those columns from the colReorder plugin.

The problem is, I do not see ANYTHING on how to implement the exclude functionality.  I only see that it is one of the features, but nothing is listed on how it call it.

Can anyone show me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/#colreorder) you can only exclude a fixed number of leftmost ([`colReorder.fixedColumnsLeft`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/colReorder.fixedColumnsLeft)) or rightmost ([`colReorder.fixedColumnsRight`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/colReorder.fixedColumnsRight)) columns.

Comment: yep, I saw that after some digging yesterday.  Bummer.  Not at all the functionality I need as I can not always guarantee that the fields to be fixed will be all left or right side.  thank you though as you are correct!